# Print a document without print preview in windows store apps

Tags: c#, winforms, winrt-xaml, printdocument, print-preview

I am developing a Windows Store application in Visual Studio 2013 using XAML and C#.
In my project, I have to print a XAML window without having print preview.

Can anybody share the code for the same?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What your application target version? Are you developing a uwp app? Without printview means not show the print UI?

Comment: Yes.UWP. Without print preview dialogue.

Comment: this cannot be done in API level. Any way, this is not a normal requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `displayedOptions.clear()` removes all of the print options from the print preview UI, including the More settings link. Be sure to append the options that you want to show on the print preview UI.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/customize-the-print-preview-ui

though this will not print directly but you can have options selection to show in print preview.